# Need to add similar customer into array after performing groupBy but with a limit per customer

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I had asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71033850/need-to-add-similar-customer-into-array-after-performing-grouby) yesterday and got a correct answer, but today I faced more issues.
So here is the new problem statement.
I am fetching customer contacts from salesforce which are coming as an array of objects as shown below.

Input Payload:

```
[
    {
        "customerID": 1,
        "customerName": "Jonhn1"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 1,
        "customerName": "Jonhn2"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 1,
        "customerName": "Jonhn3"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 1,
        "customerName": "Jonhn4"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 1,
        "customerName": "Jonhn5"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 2,
        "customerName": "Jonhn6"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 2,
        "customerName": "Jonhn7"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 2,
        "customerName": "Jonhn8"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 3,
        "customerName": "Jonhn9"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 3,
        "customerName": "Jonhn10"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 3,
        "customerName": "Jonhn11"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 4,
        "customerName": "Jonhn12"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 4,
        "customerName": "Jonhn13"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 5,
        "customerName": "Jonhn14"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 5,
        "customerName": "Jonhn15"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 5,
        "customerName": "Jonhn16"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 6,
        "customerName": "Jonhn17"
    },
    {
        "customerID": 7,
        "customerName": "Jonhn17"
    }
]
```

I need the output to be an array of arrays, each sub-array should have all the customer details of at most three different customers.
I got the solution till the above statement as show below

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
---
payload groupBy $.customerID pluck $ divideBy 3 map((flatten($)))
```

**Now the main problem,**
We have to put a limit on the number of customers in an array. For example in the given input payload customer with id "1" came more than 4 (four) times, then this customer should be in a different array ( means a separate array of customer "1" e.g an array for five records) this can happen to any other customer as well.

**So we have to check if a customer is repeating more than 4 times then make a separate array for that type of customer else combine it with other customers as required earlier**

Expected output:

```
[
    [
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "customerName": "Jonhn1"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "customerName": "Jonhn2"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "customerName": "Jonhn3"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "customerName": "Jonhn4"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "customerName": "Jonhn5"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "customerID": 2,
            "customerName": "Jonhn6"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 2,
            "customerName": "Jonhn7"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 2,
            "customerName": "Jonhn8"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 3,
            "customerName": "Jonhn9"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 3,
            "customerName": "Jonhn10"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 3,
            "customerName": "Jonhn11"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 4,
            "customerName": "Jonhn12"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 4,
            "customerName": "Jonhn13"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "customerID": 5,
            "customerName": "Jonhn14"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 5,
            "customerName": "Jonhn15"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 5,
            "customerName": "Jonhn16"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 6,
            "customerName": "Jonhn17"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 7,
            "customerName": "Jonhn18"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: What should happen if customerID 1 is only for eg 3 or 4 times and customerID 2 is greater than 4 for eg 5 or 6 times?? You also have a condition of atmost 3 separate customerID in an array . In this scenario will customerID 1 sit alone in array?? Is the order mandatory or customerID 1 can sit along with customerID 3 and 4 ?? @dheeraj kain

Comment: Thanks, @Karthik for checking this.  so if customerID 1 is only 3 or 4 times it will be clubbed with other cusomerIDs having a count less or equal to 4 . Basically, we have to make separate arrays of every customer having a count of more than 4.

Comment: as of now, I could come up here
 ((payload groupBy $.customerID pluck $)  reduce ((item, acc = []) ->   if(sizeOf(item)>4) acc + item else acc ++ item )) , this expression is creation an array for  record having count more than 4 and keeping remaining as same, if we can append remains into a single array, then we can again to group by, divide by things you shared yesterday

Comment: **WHAT SHOULD HAPPEN IF CUSTOMERID 1 IS ONLY FOR EG 3 OR 4 TIMES AND CUSTOMERID 2 IS GREATER THAN 4 FOR EG 5 OR 6 TIMES??** >> In this case customer 1 will be clubbed with another 3 customers with a similar count and there will be a separate array for customer 2.

Comment: **YOU ALSO HAVE A CONDITION OF ATMOST 3 SEPARATE CUSTOMERID IN AN ARRAY . IN THIS SCENARIO WILL CUSTOMERID 1 SIT ALONE IN ARRAY??** Yes, any customer having a count more than 4 will sit alone in a separate array

Comment: **IS THE ORDER MANDATORY OR CUSTOMERID 1 CAN SIT ALONG WITH CUSTOMERID 3 AND 4 ??**  No, the order is not mandatory, any customer can sit with any other customer having count less than or equal to 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify all the scenarios and correct me if anything I missed. I just seggregated based on the size of individual array.

If size[array] > 4 then `divideBy` 5 else `divideBy` 3.

`distinctBy` to maintain a single payload as I have used payload in if and else condition

**Note** -> Order will not be maintained as you mentioned for rainy scenarios.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var a = payload groupBy $.customerID pluck $
---
flatten(a map
    (if (sizeOf($)>4)  
            $ divideBy sizeOf($) map(flatten($))
            else
    (a filter (sizeOf ($)< 5) divideBy 3 map (flatten ($))) 
    ) distinctBy $)
```

Output

```
[
  [
    {
      "customerID": 1,
      "customerName": "Jonhn1"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 1,
      "customerName": "Jonhn2"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 1,
      "customerName": "Jonhn3"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 1,
      "customerName": "Jonhn4"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 1,
      "customerName": "Jonhn5"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "customerID": 2,
      "customerName": "Jonhn6"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 2,
      "customerName": "Jonhn7"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 2,
      "customerName": "Jonhn8"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 2,
      "customerName": "Jonhn9"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 3,
      "customerName": "Jonhn10"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 3,
      "customerName": "Jonhn11"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 4,
      "customerName": "Jonhn12"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 4,
      "customerName": "Jonhn13"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "customerID": 5,
      "customerName": "Jonhn14"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 5,
      "customerName": "Jonhn15"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 5,
      "customerName": "Jonhn16"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 6,
      "customerName": "Jonhn17"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 7,
      "customerName": "Jonhn17"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, @karthik, this is very very close to the ask.  Just the second part is coming as arrays of the array, can we somehow make them in arrays. Please see the expected output. I have to pass the whole output to parallel for each, so need everything as array or array as you did yesterday. I am really sorry If it might sound confusing. Even I am trying to take help from your expert solution to come up with the final step. Thanks a log again karthik. Just a little bit more tweak is needed.

Comment: @dheerajkain Applogies for the miss. Modified the answer. Please check now

Comment: Hi @karthik , please don't be. I know you have corrected the solution and it is with you but the solution you have posted is dividing customerID 1 into two different arrays ( please check once from your end too) I took your code and did the below modification and it is working as expected. But if you can, please provide your perfect solution. It is really really helpful Karthik, thanks a lot. Below is the modification I did

Comment: %dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var a = payload groupBy $.customerID pluck $
---
flatten(a map
    (if (sizeOf($)>4)  
            [ flatten($ divideBy 5 map(flatten($)))]
            else
    (a filter (sizeOf ($)< 5) divideBy 3 map (flatten ($))) 
    ) distinctBy $)

Comment: The dataweave you have given is giving output like below:  [
  [
    {
      "customerID": 1,
      "customerName": "Jonhn1"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 1,
      "customerName": "Jonhn2"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 1,
      "customerName": "Jonhn3"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 1,
      "customerName": "Jonhn4"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 1,
      "customerName": "Jonhn5"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "customerID": 1,
      "customerName": "Jonhn5"
    },
    {
      "customerID": 1,
      "customerName": "Jonhn5"
    }
  ],
  [....

Comment: I have added screenshot of my dwlang also @dheerajkain. Did you miss or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi @karhik, I am not able to add my screenshot here. Need to learn. Could you please add two more objects for customerId 1 and then see the output> I was validating your answers for different scenario and added two more objects with customer ID 1.  Could you please try and see, and let me think I am I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Please check now. Got my mistake @dheerajkain

Comment: Thanks a lot, Karthik, this worked as expected. You really are a dataweave wizard. Appreciate your help and time :)

Answer (score 2):

I was about to post the answer but Karthik posted, But below is the correct code that @dheerajkain is asking

If any customer came more than four times (e.g., 6 or 7 soon), then a separate array is required for that customer?

Also, as you mentioned in the comments, there is no sizing limit if one array has three customers and each customer less than four times (each customer less than or equal to 4 times)?

if it is, then try the below code:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var customer = payload groupBy $.customerID pluck $
---
flatten(customer map
    (if (sizeOf($)>4)  
          [flatten($ divideBy 5 map(flatten($)))]
            else
    (customer filter (sizeOf ($)< 5) divideBy 3 map (flatten ($))) 
    ) distinctBy $)
```

Comment: Thanks, @anurag , yes this is also giving the expected output, thanks for putting efforts