# Need to add similar customer into array after performing groupBy but with a limit per customer and now with array size restriction

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I had asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71045910/need-to-add-similar-customer-into-array-after-performing-groupby-but-with-a-limi) a few days back and got the correct answers, but again we faced new issues. So here is the new problem statement. I am fetching customer contacts from salesforce which are coming as an array of objects as shown below.

Input Payload:

```
    [
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "contactName": "Jonhn1"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "contactName": "Jonhn2"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "contactName": "Jonhn3"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "contactName": "Jonhn4"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "contactName": "Jonhn5"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 2,
            "contactName": "Jonhn6"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 2,
            "contactName": "Jonhn7"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 2,
            "contactName": "Jonhn8"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 2,
            "contactName": "Jonhn8"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 3,
            "contactName": "Jonhn9"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 3,
            "contactName": "Jonhn10"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 4,
            "contactName": "Jonhn12"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 4,
            "contactName": "Jonhn13"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 5,
            "contactName": "Jonhn14"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 5,
            "contactName": "Jonhn15"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 5,
            "contactName": "Jonhn16"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 6,
            "contactName": "Jonhn17"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 7,
            "contactName": "Jonhn17"
        }
    ]
```

I needed the output to be an array of arrays, each sub-array should have all the customer details of at most three different customers and We had to put a limit on the number of customers in an array. I got the solution till the above statement as shown below

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var a = payload groupBy $.customerID pluck $
---
flatten(a map
    (if (sizeOf($)>4)  
            $ divideBy sizeOf($) map(flatten($))
            else
    (a filter (sizeOf ($)<= 4) divideBy 3 map (flatten ($))) 
    ) distinctBy $)
```

**NEW PROBLEM:**

```
flatten(a map
        (if (sizeOf($)>4)  
                $ divideBy sizeOf($) map(flatten($))
                else
```

above part of the solution is just fine.

```
 (a filter (sizeOf ($)<= 4) divideBy 3 map (flatten ($))) 
    ) distinctBy $)
```

I want some logic in this part. We want each array to have a max of 4 records.
In the given example, there will be a separate array for customer 1, and for remaining, customers create arrays having a maximum of 4 entries, if after adding two customer array sizes is exceeding more than 4, put them in different arrays. If after adding 3 customers in an array size is less than 4, keep them in the same array.

**Background**
As we have to send each array to the SAP Function module which takes 10 minutes to update 1000 records and our dedicated load balance gives gateway timeout after 10 minutes.
So we have to send max records and also want to avoid timeout issues ( we have to use dlb we cant call workers directly ).

expected output :

```
[
    [
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "customerName": "Jonhn1"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "customerName": "Jonhn2"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "customerName": "Jonhn3"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "customerName": "Jonhn4"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 1,
            "customerName": "Jonhn5"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "customerID": 2,
            "customerName": "Jonhn6"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 2,
            "customerName": "Jonhn7"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 2,
            "customerName": "Jonhn8"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 2,
            "customerName": "Jonhn6"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "customerID": 3,
            "customerName": "Jonhn9"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 3,
            "customerName": "Jonhn10"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 4,
            "customerName": "Jonhn12"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 4,
            "customerName": "Jonhn13"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "customerID": 5,
            "customerName": "Jonhn14"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 5,
            "customerName": "Jonhn15"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 5,
            "customerName": "Jonhn16"
        },
        {
            "customerID": 6,
            "customerName": "Jonhn17"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "customerID": 7,
            "customerName": "Jonhn17"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: Dheeraj, you just need a sizing on each array now where we have  3 different customers in an array?

Comment: Right @AnuragSharma, each array should have constraints on max entries.

Comment: dheeraj did you get answer for this?

Comment: Not yet @AnuragSharma

Comment: i thought someone replieed here, but can you try reduce function?

Comment: this is lilttle sconfusing becasue you said,you want each array to have a max of 4 records. but you are saying this too that If after adding 3 customers in an array size is less than six, keep them in the array.

Comment: dheeraj,could you please clarify this?

Comment: Hi @AnuragSharma sorry for the late reply, if we talk about second logic, I can have a max of 4 records in an array. Sorry that 6 was a typo, "If after adding 3 customers in an array size is less than 4, keep them in the same array"

Comment: did correction in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242007/discussion-between-anurag-sharma-and-dheeraj-kain).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code that gives the expected output.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var a = payload groupBy $.customerID pluck $
---
flatten(a map
    (if (sizeOf($)>4)  
            $ divideBy sizeOf($) map(flatten($))
            else
    (a filter (sizeOf ($)< 5) reduce ($$++$) divideBy 4) 
    ) distinctBy $)
```

As I said in my comments, try to use reduce.